# Spring Security 3 SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler not saving original request

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to configure spring security 3 so that when a users is forced to login again (eg. when the session has timed out) the user will be taken back the the page they where on before the authorisation process began.

I am using a `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` but the original request does not seem to be saved in the cache.

Below is my security configuration.

```xml
<security:http auto-config="false" 
               use-expressions="true"
               access-denied-page="/views/auth/login?error=true"
               entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"  >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/views/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/data/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/*" access="permitAll" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/views/auth/login" logout-url="/views/auth/logout" />
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/views/auth/login" >
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </security:session-management>
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager />

<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="com.security.web.filter.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">             
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="aAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="com.security.web.manager.AuthenticationManager" />

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/views/auth/login"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/views/auth/login?error=true"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/views"/>
</bean>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to go back to the original request but the session has timed out?

Answer (score 3):

*I know this question is old, but I wanted to document what I found for others.*

### Short Answer

The problem is that if you use the *invalid-session-url* on the **<session-management>** tag, then the original request will not be saved in the cache.

### Explanation

This is discussed at the spring source forum:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?89352-requestCache-null-when-using-session-management-gt-invalid-session-url

In the above forum, Luke Taylor, a senior member of the security team says:

> The invalid-session-url implies that the previous session has expired and the user should start again. There's no connection with the RequestCache which is used for restoring a request after a user has logged in.

and

> When a session expires you can't know that it is safe to continue with the requested URL as some required state may have been lost along with the session. It may be OK in your particular case, but it's not a safe assumption in general.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing this :

```
<bean id="requestCacheAwareFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="requestCache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache"/>
```

also you need to add requestCache been to authenticationSuccessHandler

```
<property name="requestCache" ref="requestCache"/>
```